# Nativescript RadAutoComplete doesn't show lists by a middle word

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular, nativescript-telerik-ui

I'm using `RadAutoComplete` in order to search in a list. for example, this is my list:

- Rolex | Date Just | Man
- Rolex | Yacht Master ||

If a user types `Rolex` the list will show correctly but he types `Date`, it won't show anything. 
I want if the user typed `Date` that is the middle word, the list would show.

I have read the document already but haven't found anything about that. 
please anyone can help me?

Update: 
This is the [playground sample](https://play.nativescript.org/?_ga=2.254421384.1663967882.1561178363-402141925.1546236309&template=play-ng&id=Mqkd2U).

Thanks

Comment: Have you set `completionMode` to `Contains`, if it still fails please share Playground Sample where the issue can be reproduced.

Comment: Can you share your piece of code?

Comment: @Manoj here you are https://play.nativescript.org/?_ga=2.254421384.1663967882.1561178363-402141925.1546236309&template=play-ng&id=Mqkd2U

Comment: @Narendra here you are https://play.nativescript.org/?_ga=2.254421384.1663967882.1561178363-402141925.1546236309&template=play-ng&id=Mqkd2U

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the `completionMode` to `Contains` if you like a full text search instead of start with.

```
<RadAutoCompleteTextView automationText="RadAutoCompleteTextView"
                    row="0" col="1" class="RadAutoCompleteTextView" hint="Search"
                    [items]="dataItems" suggestMode="SuggestAppend"
                    displayMode="Plain" showCloseButton="true" completionMode="Contains">
```

[Updated Playground](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=Mqkd2U&v=2)